# ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 8 after created the API Access in google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I had created a service account name with "can edit" to access the Google cloud storage. I used the sample application provided in [Complete sample Application](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/overview#Complete_Sample_App) for java and deployed in app engine. when call the servlet in browser am getting error like this,

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.io.IOException
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.translateException(FileServiceImpl.java:615)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:588)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.create(FileServiceImpl.java:506)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.createNewGSFile(FileServiceImpl.java:153)
    at com.audioapp.ListpeopleServlet.doGet(ListpeopleServlet.java:36)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 8: 
    at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1495)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.doSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:240)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.access$000(ApiProxyImpl.java:66)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:183)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:180)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:180)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:66)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:107)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:584)
```

can anyone suggest me to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you grant access as explained in the docs [1] -> under **5. Give permissions to your bucket or objects.**)?

Which SDK version do you use? Maybe it's an old SDK version that is causing this exception.

[1] https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/overview

Comment: yes, i had created the service account name and granted the "can edit" option too. Also am using the App engine version 1.7.3. Can you tell me a brief description what to do under step 5. i created the service account name using oAuth access provided by api access tab. am i missing anything. kindly guide me

Comment: If you added your service account (looks like PROJECTNAME@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) as a team member of your Google APIs the access should work. Please post the code where the exception appeared: com.audioapp.ListpeopleServlet.doGet(ListpeopleServlet.java:36)

Comment: i got the service account as you said do i need to give this account id anywhere in my application

Comment: AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService.openWriteChannel(writableFile, lock); This is the line where am getting error. As i told above the complete sample application, the same code i used

Comment: AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService.openWriteChannel(writableFile, lock); is not possible :) , because openWriteChannel does not return an AppEngineFile. Did you create the bucket as defined in the BUCKET_NAME variable of the example? If not, you can create it in the [API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) under Google Cloud Storage -> online browser.

Comment: i got cleared the error thank you da_re. Now i got a new problem which i posted in this link can you view it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984979/how-can-i-upload-a-file-in-google-cloud-storage-using-gae

Comment: Please say how you fixed the exception to help other people with the same problem :) . Thanks.

Comment: As you mentioned in the above answer i manually set the ACL. The Service account name in GAE and in Google Cloud Storage differed in domain that's the problem. So that i set the ACL as per your suggestion and the error got cleared. Thanks da_re